# Can someone explain this weird behaviour in PHP strtotime

Tags: php, timestamp

I am working on a calendar function that should output the name of the week and the date where I have the weeknumber and year

The code works fine when the year is 2018, but as soon as it is 2019, something goes wrong

```
echo date("Y-m-d D", strtotime("monday 2018W37")); // outputs 2018-09-10 Mon
echo date("Y-m-d D", strtotime("monday 2019W37")); // outputs 2019-09-15 Sun
```

But if you check a valid calendar, a monday in week 37 2019 is of cause a monday and the date is 2019-09-09

Can someone explain this behaviour and maybe provide an alternative to strtotime.

Comment: FWIW, I would never rely on `strtotime` magically parsing any sort of vague freeform specification I supply. It's doing a ton of different things, and it can't possibly all do them equally well. I'd calculate this "by hand" instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write it like this,

```
echo date("Y-m-d D", strtotime("2018W37")) . "\n"; // outputs 2018-09-10 Mon
echo date("Y-m-d D", strtotime("2019W37")) . "\n"; // outputs 2019-09-9 Mon
```

or

```
echo date("Y-m-d D", strtotime("2018W37-1")) . "\n"; // outputs 2018-09-10 Mon
echo date("Y-m-d D", strtotime("2019W37-1")) . "\n"; // outputs 2019-09-9 Mon
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not have to specify "Monday" in the string, so use:

```
echo date("Y-m-d D", strtotime("2018W37")); 
echo date("Y-m-d D", strtotime("2019W37"));
```

Which returns:

```
2018-09-10 Mon
2019-09-09 Mon
```